# How to find integer values within a String in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, string, oracle, date

I am trying to calculate tenure in years based on data in this format 2 year(s), 11 month(s), 5 day(s). Below is the logic in oracle. I am trying to implement similar solution in SQL Server. Can you please help?

In this example 2 year(s), 11 month(s), 5 day(s) is converted to 2.93 years.

```
round( 
    (regexp_substr(tenure_in_current_job,'[^ ]+')
    + REGEXP_REPLACE(tenure_in_current_job,'(.*r\(s\), )(\d+)(.*)','\2')/12
    + REGEXP_REPLACE(tenure_in_current_job,'(.*h\(s\), )(\d+)(.*)','\2')/365),
2 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select sum(num.val * 1.0 / case when trm.val like '%year%' then 1 when trm.val like '%month%' then 12 else 365 end)
from string_split('2 year(s), 11 month(s), 5 day(s)',',')
     cross apply (select ltrim("value")) trm(val)
     cross apply (select cast(left(trm.val,charindex(' ',trm.val)-1) as int)) num(val)
```

```
--------------
2.930365296802
```

1. Split the string on commas
2. Remove leading spaces on each of the 3 resulting rows
3. Remove everything from the first space onward, and cast as int
4. Divide the resulting int by 1, 12, or 365 as appropriate

Caveat: [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) was introduced in SQL Server 2016.  If you're on SQL 2012 or older, this solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response and it works like a charm. Appreciate it!